# Height of SVG#tspan using getBBox() returns wrong value in Firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, firefox

When applying `getBBox()` to the child of `tspan#t18yiifj` the returned height is ~18 in Firefox (wrong) and ~450 in Chrome/Edge (correct).

SVG-excerpt

```xml
    <g id="dynam_10206" class="dynam" style="cursor: pointer;" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)" stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)">
      <text x="7465" y="1690" font-size="0px">
        <tspan id="tcbd4q9" class="text">
          <tspan font-size="405px" class="text">cresc</tspan>
        </tspan>
        <tspan id="supplied_1234a" class="supplied highlighted">
          <tspan id="t18yiifj" class="text">
            <tspan font-size="405px" class="text">endo</tspan>
          </tspan>
        </tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
```

JS

```js
elem = document.getElementById('t18yiifj'); 
elemChild = elem.querySelectorAll("tspan[font-size]")[0];
console.log("elemChild BBox:", elemChild.getBBox());

/* console.log("elemBox rects: ", elemChild.getBoundingClientRect()); */
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OSE_0501/ma1o05b7/5/#&togetherjs=r9ouB7qDaa).

As alternative I also tried to get the coordinates of the `tspan#t18yiifj` and its parent, but getting 0 in all browsers.

```js
elem = document.getElementById('t18yiifj'); 
console.log("elem BBox:", elem.getBBox());

elemParent = elem.closest('.supplied');
console.log("elemParent BBox:", elemParent.getBBox());
```

Returns

```
[object SVGRect] {
  height: 0,
  width: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}
```

Comment: I think `tspan` tags cannot be nested

Comment: but it is working in chrome and edge ...

Comment: A `<tspan>` element can be placed within another `<tspan>` element. Quote from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan): The SVG `<tspan>` element defines a subtext **within** a `<text>` element or **another `<tspan>` element.**. You can also use [this validator](https://validator.w3.org/check)

Comment: yes, but why firefox does not get the correct height?

Comment: @qrsngky You are right, I was wrong about `tspan` nesting. Anyway, I would suggest to try to simplify the DOM structure and see if it affects the results

Comment: The value in Firefox is affected by `viewBox="0 0 21060 8320"` in the `<svg clas="definition-scale"` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a Firefox bug

### Workaround

If you just need to get the current text height you could retrieve it from the parent `<text>` element's bbox.

```
let bbTxt = endo.closest('text').getBBox();
let spanH = bbTxt.height;
```

For the exact `<tspan>` bbox we can create a helper funtion using [`getExtentOfChar()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTextContentElement)

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('t18yiifj');
let tspanText = elem.querySelector("tspan[font-size]");
let bbT = getBBoxTspan(tspanText);

// example render bbox
let ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
let bbRect = document.createElementNS(ns, 'rect');
svg.append(bbRect);
bbRect.setAttribute('x', bbT.x)
bbRect.setAttribute('y', bbT.y)
bbRect.setAttribute('width', bbT.width)
bbRect.setAttribute('height', bbT.height)
bbRect.setAttribute('fill', 'none')
bbRect.setAttribute('stroke', 'red')
bbRect.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0.2%')

// calculate tspan bbox helper
function getBBoxTspan(el) {
  // sanitize whitespace
  let chars = el.textContent;
  let charsArr = chars.split('');
  let bb0 = el.getExtentOfChar(0);
  let bb1 = el.getExtentOfChar(charsArr.length - 1);

  // total bbox
  let bb = {
    x: bb0.x,
    y: bb0.y,
    width: (bb1.x + bb1.width) - bb0.x,
    height: bb0.height
  }
  return bb;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 75%;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 10000 10000">
  <g id="dynam_10206" class="dynam" style="cursor: pointer;" fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)" stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)">
    <text x="7465" y="1690" font-size="0px">
      <tspan id="tcbd4q9" class="text">
        <tspan font-size="405px" class="text">cresc</tspan>
      </tspan>
      <tspan id="supplied_1234a" class="supplied highlighted">
        <tspan id="t18yiifj" class="text">
          <tspan font-size="405px" class="text">endo</tspan>
        </tspan>
      </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

We're actually getting the bounding box of the first and last character/textNode within the selected tspan and calculate a total bbox like so:

```
let bb0 = el.getExtentOfChar(0);
let bb1 = el.getExtentOfChar(charsArr.length - 1);

let bb = {
  x: bb0.x,
  y: bb0.y,
  width: (bb1.x+bb1.width)-bb0.x,
  height: bb0.height
}
```

Comment: You could leave out the whitespace bit if you get the total `tspan` width just with `el.getComputedTextLength()`. This and a few other methods work on rendered, [addressable characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TermAddressableCharacter).

Comment: @ccprog: Got me =). I've revised the code example. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The approach with `.closest('text').getBBox();` returned 0 in FF. But the `getBBoxTspan();`  works fine!